# Oracle: query help for data conversion

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables containing same value. One table contains numeric values where are other contains character wise corresponding values. For example if first table contains value '11', the second table contains '3131'. If first table contains '123', second value contains '313233'.

I need to write an SQL statement that joins these table (in other words I need to know a function that either converts '11' to '3131' or vice versa.).

Comment: Give us the sample tables and the result table you want and we'll give you the SQL statement. Your example statement scenario doesn't make sense.

Comment: why would you do that? what is the use of making `999-->3939393` ?

Comment: Actually I already have two tables containing these values and I wanted to join. I found answer to the question and have posted it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it using RAWTOHEX function. 
Applying rawtohex function on first table's column gave the expected result.

```
select RAWTOHEX('11') from dual;

RAWTOHEX('11')
-----------------------------------
 3131
```

Thanks.